# Member Entitlement Management VSTS API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been trying to work with the Member Entitlement Management VSTS API in Visual Studio. I am attempting to get the user entitlement summary, and am receiving an API locator error.

http://Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssResourceNotFoundException : API resource location 5ae55b13-c9dd-49d1-957e-6e76c152e3d9 is not registered on https://tfs-test/tfs.

I have attempted to add the collection to the URL and dress it up as much as I can like the REST API call on the MSDN page, but am having no luck. I have noticed that the MSDN page has a section on oauth2, but I have been using a PAT. I cannot find any reference to oauth2 for on-prem TFS 2018, is this not possible?

[MSDN - Get User Summary API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlement%20summary/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue , it is because `User Entitlement Summary - Get` rest api is only available for VSTS(azure devops), does not support on-premise TFS. TFS APIs currently doesn't support to get access level.

When you switch the rest api version to `TFS2018 U2`, you will get this prompt:

> The requested page is not available for Team Foundation Server 2018
>   U2. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page
>   is available for.

[image]

You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/261208/tfs-rest-apiclient-api-to-provide-basicstakeholder.html) for the similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response Hugh. Is there something similar to this available in a CLI or some such? We need to provide user entitlements and access to our RBAC team and I was hoping to be able to utilize this API for that information.

Comment: I am afraid there is currently no way to get user entitlements rights for tfs. Apart from the negative answer, I think what you want is a good idea! So I post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/879778/get-user-entitlements-for-tfs.html) in DC forum. Anyone interested in this can vote for it and track it. Hope this helps.